# using structure instead of class

Tags: c++

I have never learned class but I do get the general idea and I'm trying it out.
The following code found online, making stacks using linked list and I'm wondering if we used structure instead of class what would this program look like?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;


//   Creating a NODE Structure
struct node
{
int data;
struct node *next;
};

// Creating a class STACK
class stack
{
struct node *top;
public:
stack() // constructure
{
    top=NULL;
}
void push(); // to insert an element
void pop();  // to delete an element
void show(); // to show the stack
};
// PUSH Operation
void stack::push()
{
int value;
struct node *ptr;
cout<<"nPUSH Operationn";
cout<<"Enter a number to insert: ";
cin>>value;
ptr=new node;
ptr->data=value;
ptr->next=NULL;
if(top!=NULL)
    ptr->next=top;
top=ptr;
cout<<"nNew item is inserted to the stack!!!";

}

// POP Operation
void stack::pop()
{
 struct node *temp;
 if(top==NULL)
 {
    cout<<"nThe stack is empty!!!";
 }
 temp=top;
 top=top->next;
 cout<<"nPOP Operation........nPoped value is "<<temp->data;
 delete temp;
 }

// Show stack
void stack::show()
{
struct node *ptr1=top;
cout<<"nThe stack isn";
while(ptr1!=NULL)
{
    cout<<ptr1->data<<" ->";
    ptr1=ptr1->next;
}
cout<<"NULLn";
}

// Main function
int main()
{
stack s;
int choice;
while(1)
{
    cout<<"n-----------------------------------------------------------";
    cout<<"nttSTACK USING LINKED LISTnn";
    cout<<"1:PUSHn2:POPn3:DISPLAY STACKn4:EXIT";
    cout<<"nEnter your choice(1-4): ";
    cin>>choice;
    switch(choice)
    {
        case 1:
            s.push();
            break;
        case 2:
            s.pop();
            break;
        case 3:
            s.show();
            break;
        case 4:
            return 0;
            break;
        default:
            cout<<"Please enter correct choice(1-4)!!";
            break;
     }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Just wondering what would this code look like if we were to use a structure instead of class?

Comment: You should learn C++ with a book, not by looking at "code found online". The code which you have found here is terrible and would not survive any professional code review.

Comment: As for your question, did you **try** it? What happened?

Answer (score 2):

Struct is almost like a class. In Struct elements default are public, in class they are private.

Comment: Default base class access level is also different.

Answer (score -2):

Think about this little example here:

```
class TestClass
{
   int foo(void)
   {
      return (a * a);  // is equal to: return (this->a * this->a);
   }

   int a;
};


TestClass example;

example.foo();   // execute function foo of class TestClass with data of instance example
```

Rewriting the above using a struct would look something like this:

```
struct TestClass 
{
   int a;
}

/* "struct implementation" of foo function */
int TestClass_foo(struct TestClass *this)
{
   return (this->a * this->a);
}

struct TestClass example;

TestClass_foo(&example);   // execute function TestClass_foo with data of example
```

So let's note the differences when using structs in the above example:

- You have to pass a pointer to the actual instance of the struct to each call of function `TestClass_foo`.
- Naming of the functions like "TestClass_foo" gets messy pretty quickly...

So in this simple example the benefits of a class do not look too impressive. But with this you get an idea of the basic differences.

But once you start using inheritance or member visibility (public, private, protected) you cannot do it using structs (or just with enormous overhead). But this is what C++ is for so you don't have to think about how the compiler makes your code work.

Comment: This answer is full of technical inaccuracies and errors. I don't know where to start. You do not seem to realise that `class` and `struct` are **almost identical** in C++. A `struct` can do everything that a `class` can. You can use `public`, `protected` and `private`, there is zero "overhead" and you don't need any of this pointer stuff.

Comment: @ChristianHackl: You're totally right about that. I think I was a bit unclear with my answer. I for my part don't use structs in C++. When I see structs I think of C. Using C you can "fake" simple classes using code like my second example but this gets messy pretty quickly...